# How can i implement the "do not show again" functionality on my activity?

Tags: java, android

> Basically i have a splash screen followed by a getting started activity with a button at the bottom and a checkbox to not show again
>   said activity. How can i implement it so that it does what i intend it
>   to do? I am a self taught new developer. I don't need the answer to be
>   straight forward, just point me in the right direction.

```
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/do_not_show_again"
            android:layout_width="249dp"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/do_not_show_again"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.513"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/get_started_button" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Set a listener on the checkbox, when clicked, store a boolean in shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use Splash activity. there is no use of delaying the user 3 or 4 seconds . Instead use a full view Fragment which will be helpful to load the UI elements of Main Activity.
store Boolean in shared prefs for disappear fragment permanently.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to store your checkbox value on on shared preference.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpref = getSharedPreferences("shared_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor sharedpref_editor = sharedpref.edit();;
```

confirm if the checkbox is check via onClick then store boolean true on tag "skip"

```
YOUR_BUTTON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    if (YOUR_CHECKBOX.isChecked()) {

         sharedpref_editor.putBoolean("skip", true);
         sharedpref_editor.apply();

    }
  }
});
```

then next time you open the activity, your program should check the value in shared preferences under the tag "skip" by doing this on your onCreate Activity.

```
Boolean saveSkip = sharedpref.getBoolean("skip", false);
if(saveSkip){

  Intent skipIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourTargetActivity.class);
  startActivity(skipIntent);
  finish();

}
```

Comment: kindly add some comments along with the code - code only answers are considered low quality